# Свидения о Иосифа прекрасного

Tags: литература

Прошу вас мне дать сведения об Иосифе прекрасном. Проработать проблемы с источниками и их связь с восточными мотивами

Answer (score 3):

[Тык](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Answer (score 0):

behemothus, скажите, это Вы такую метку установили? Другую и не придумаешь для

> Раработать проблемы с источниками и их связь с восточними мотивами

А ответ Ваш - замечательный! Тык...А как же "разработать проблемы с источниками?" ))) И почему у меня никогда не принимают ответ из трех знаков?

Автору вопроса: Вы, по-моему, обратились не по адресу. Мы ничего не "разрабатываем" и никаких научных работ не пишем.

Comment: Я, конечно. Но только потому, что там в оригинале была какая-то цифирь.
А вы какими знаками пользуетесь? Может не теми?

Comment: Букв-то больше, чем три: это ведь ссылка!

Comment: Три буквы, три буквы, три буквы...